# How to create CollectionView global object Which can be accessible from any controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to create `CollectionView` global object Which can be accessible from any `Controller`?
I want to create an `UICollectionView` which can by accessible from any view controller, and display `CollectionView` on Same `Controller` from where it called.

Comment: 1 - Take it in Base class, and inherit the base class.
2 - Take a global in AppDelegate
3 - Can use Singleton class

Comment: You probably want to just create new instances of a UICollectionView subclass and have a global data source if it needs to display the same data.

Comment: I wan't to do it like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303580/how-to-set-delegate-to-uicollectionview-in-nsobject-controller/39316468#39316468 can you please help me in that.

Comment: i_am_jorf you are correct, I want to use same data. But i not able to set delegate to collection view object. So it show's white portion. No delegate called. Just stocked there. is there any other way? any example?

Comment: reason for down vote question?

Answer (score 0):

You can a use singleton:

```
@interface CollectionViewSingleton : UICollectionView

+ (id)shared;

@end

@implementation CollectionViewSingleton

+ (id)shared {
    static CollectionViewSingleton *shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Marco sorry for late, but I want to know that Can I put other View's in this, with collection view?